# Looking For A Good HTML Templater for PHP

Tags: php, html, haml, templating

That's an HTML templater, not a php templater, not java or whatever.

I am looking for something like HAML for PHP. I tried the 2 projects for PHP, PHAML and PHPHaml both of which are suffering from serious bugs.

Do you know of any good html templater out there, preferably for PHP?

**EDIT** I''m looking for something that can turn this

```
<h1>Heading</h1>
<p>entry</p>
<blockquote>quote</blockquote>
```

to something like this

```
h1 : heading
p : entry
blockquote : quote
```

something like what [phphaml](http://phphaml.sourceforge.net/) does

Comment: If I understood correctly, you need templating engine for PHP?
Smarty maybe? http://www.smarty.net/

Comment: sorry, smarty was not an option for me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you look at textile?

http://textism.com/tools/textile/

Look at the example syntax on the right hand side, here is an example...

```
h2{color:green}. This is a title

h3. This is a subhead

p{color:red}. This is some text of dubious character. Isn't the use of "quotes" just lazy writing -- and theft of 'intellectual property' besides? I think the time has come to see a block quote.
```

Converts to:

```
<h2 style="color:green;">This is a title</h2>

<h3>This is a subhead</h3>

<p style="color:red;">This is some text of dubious character. Isn&#8217;t the use of &#8220;quotes&#8221; just lazy writing&#8212;and theft of &#8216;intellectual property&#8217; besides? I think the time has come to see a block quote.</p>
```

There are other examples at the bottom of the right sidebar.

Comment: this is so good! do they have a parser I can use with PHP? I guess not :(

Comment: They do, a friend has been using it for a PHP based MicroCMS he's buidling.Here's the main page (http://textile.thresholdstate.com/) and here is the zip with the PHP class (http://textile.thresholdstate.com/file_download/1/textile-2.0.0.zip)

Answer (score 0):

Try http://haml-to-php.com/ which is a complete rewrite of phamlp based on a minimal parser engine.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this: http://github.com/mo-zag/watcher. There's a guide on how to add PHP code inside Ruby Haml files. This watcher will watch the files and save them into your given folder. It's quite simple to set up, too. You don't need to use any PHP template parsers, you just use the native Haml and Sass in Ruby.